# Window switching and threading in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt

I am working on GUI with PyQT. My goal is to make a program that reads the id from RFID card and switches windows after reading.

My current problem is that when I run the program the first window (lock screen) won't show at all, but after reading the card the second window(menu) shows up. I can't find my way this problem. My first try was without threading at all but I thought threading would help on this problem, but I ended up in same situation. Reading the card works and so on, but I assume problem is on Qt as I dont have lot of experience with Qt.

```
class ThreadRFID(QtCore.QThread):

   signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str, int)
   successSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

   def __del__(self):
      self.wait()

   def read(self):
       #Initialize RFID Reader
       reader = SimpleMFRC522()
       while True:
           #here reading the card and processing data...
           id, text = reader.read()
           self.successSignal.emit()

class UILock(object):
   def __init__(self):
       super(UILock, self).__init__()

   def setupUI(self, MainWindow):
       MainWindow.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 450)
       MainWindow.setFixedSize(400, 450)
       MainWindow.setWindowTitle("UILockTab")

 class UIMenu(object):
   def __init__(self):
       super(UIMenu, self).__init__()

   def setupUI(self, MainWindow):
       MainWindow.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 450)
       MainWindow.setFixedSize(400, 450)
       MainWindow.setWindowTitle("UIWindow")

 class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
       self.UILock = UILock()
       self.UIMenu = UIMenu()
       self.startLockTab()

   def startLockTab(self):
       self.UILock.setupUI(self)
       self.show()
       self.myThread = ThreadRFID(self)
       self.myThread.read()
       self.myThread.successSignal.connect(self.UIMenu.setupUI)

   def startUIWindow(self):
       self.UIMenu.setupUI(self)
       self.show()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     import sys
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     MW = MainWindow()
     MW.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using threads incorrectly. If you inherit `QThread`, you should only call `start()` from main thread and in `QThread`'s `run()` method place all operations, if you call thread methods from main `thread` they got executed in main thread (`myThread.read()` runs in main thread and blocks event loop until return from `read()`).

```py
class ThreadRFID(QtCore.QThread):
   ...
    def run(self):
        reader = SimpleMFRC522()
        while True:
            id, text = reader.read()
            self.successSignal.emit()

class UIMenu(object):
    ...
    def startLockTab(self):
        self.UILock.setupUI(self)
        self.show()
        self.myThread = ThreadRFID(self)
        self.myThread.start()
        self.myThread.successSignal.connect(self.UIMenu.setupUI)
```